# How can i draw the below shape in flutter

Tags: flutter

This is the shape i need.
[image: screenshot]

I tried with customclipper but did not got expected output.

```
int curveHeight = 20;
Offset controlPoint = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height + curveHeight);
Offset endPoint = Offset(size.width , size.height - curveHeight);

Path path = Path()
  ..lineTo(0, size.height - curveHeight)
  ..quadraticBezierTo(controlPoint.dx , controlPoint.dy , endPoint.dx , endPoint.dy )
  ..lineTo(size.width , 0)
  ..close();
```

output [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I am using CustomPaint for this. You can also use `arcToPoint` while the control points will be used to shift on semantic shape.

```dart
class CustomHeaderPaint extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final circleRadius =
        size.width / 4; //use math.min if you want the smallest side

    Path path = Path()
      ..lineTo(circleRadius, 0)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(0, circleRadius),
        radius: Radius.circular(circleRadius * .8), //play with this value
        clockwise: true,
      );
    canvas.drawPath(
        path,
        Paint()
          ..color = Colors.deepPurple
          ..style = PaintingStyle.fill);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

The similar thing is for brazier curve

```dart
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final circleRadius =
        size.width / 4; //use math.min if you want the smallest side

    double x1 = circleRadius * .95; //play with this value
    double y1 = circleRadius * .95;

    Path path = Path()
      ..lineTo(circleRadius, 0)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(x1, y1, 0, circleRadius);
    canvas.drawPath(
        path,
        Paint()
          ..color = Colors.deepPurple
          ..style = PaintingStyle.fill);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CustomPaint(
  size: Size(500,(500*0.5833333333333334).toDouble()), //You can Replace [WIDTH] with your desired width for Custom Paint and height will be calculated automatically
  painter: RPSCustomPainter(),
),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RPSCustomPainter extends CustomPainter{
  
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    
    

  // Circle
  
  Paint paint_fill_1 = Paint()
      ..color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 34, 54, 251)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = size.width*0.00
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt
      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.miter;
     
         
    Path path_1 = Path();
    path_1.moveTo(size.width*0.0810583,size.height*0.0007714);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.1124917,size.height*0.0007714,size.width*0.1707333,size.height*0.1402714,size.width*0.1449250,size.height*0.2287286);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.1208417,size.height*0.3211429,size.width*0.0559583,size.height*0.3214286,size.width*0.0009417,size.height*0.3214286);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.0001000,size.height*0.2538000,size.width*0.0003750,size.height*0.2487714,size.width*0.0009417,size.height*0.0046571);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.0159167,size.height*0.0133286,size.width*-0.0456000,size.height*0.0026857,size.width*0.0810583,size.height*0.0007714);
    path_1.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path_1, paint_fill_1);
  

  // Circle
  
  Paint paint_stroke_1 = Paint()
      ..color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = size.width*0.00
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt
      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.miter;
     
         
    
    canvas.drawPath(path_1, paint_stroke_1);
  
    
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
  
}
```

[image]

If you want more custom designs use this [site](https://fluttershapemaker.com/#/)